# Ruby error when trying to push a document to a Mongoid 'embeds_many' collection using an initialise call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mongoid

I have a class Submittable, which embeds_many Submissions. I have an rspec test where I want to push a new Submission to the Submittable.submissions collection. If I initialise the Submission using a hash it works, but if I use an Initialise call, it fails telling me

> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
>   ./spec/models/submittable_spec.rb:14:in`block (4 levels) in '

**Submittable**

```
class Submittable
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :course_booking
  embeds_many :submissions

  field :week, type: Integer
  field :topic_name, type: String
  field :date_due, type: Date
  field :date_submitted, type: Date

end
```

**Submission**

```
class Submission
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :submittable

  field :date_submitted, type: Date
  field :normal_mistakes, type: Integer
  field :challenge_questions_attempted, type: Integer
  field :challenge_questions_mistakes, type: Integer

  def initialize(date_submitted, normal_mistakes)
    @date_submitted = date_submitted
    @normal_mistakes = normal_mistakes
  end

end
```

**Submittable_spec**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Submittable do

  context "submittable with submissions" do
    before {
      @submittable = Submittable.new
    }
    describe "one complete submission" do
      before {
        #WORKS (if Submission#initialise is removed)
        #@submittable.submissions << Submission.new(date_submitted: Date.today, normal_mistakes: 0)
        #DOES NOT WORK
        @submittable.submissions << Submission.new(Date.today, 0)
      }
      it "should be complete" do
        expect(@submittable.complete?).to eq(true)
      end
    end
```

I am fairly new to ruby, so it could be something quite obvious, but why would initialising with a hash behave differently to using an initialise method?

I am using mongoid (3.1.5), ruby 2.0.0, and rails (3.2.13)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mongoid::Document#intialize` requires some parameters ([rdoc](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Document)):

```
initialize(attrs = nil, options = nil)
```

Your implementation overrides that, which is causing Mongoid some confusion. If you wanted to override `initialize` you'd need to accept these parameters and call `super`. I would suggest avoiding it - it's one of the prices you pay for having such an unobtrusive API.

The best solution is to leave `initialize` alone and use your first approach - `Submission.new(date_submitted: Date.today, normal_mistakes: 0)`.

Comment: Makes sense - I didn't realise I was overriding the Mongoid method. Thanks!